# systemd service wants/after optional

Tags: systemd

I am using strongswan VPN on production for some client applications. Upon reboot strongswan is not loading up (needs some time after network-online.service).

I was able to "delay" the rest of the services that need VPN by adding to the [Unit] section the

```
[Unit]
Wants=strongswan.service
After=network-online.service strongswan.service
```

As the same service is running to a non vpn environment, this will fail. Is there an "optional" way to use Wants/After?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Wants= is the optional way, as Requires= is the mandatory way.
I've seen a different post here explaining to the systemd man page.

Thank you all.